# Why Can't I Import this Enum Correctly?

Tags: python, enums

I have a Enum.

```
   from enum import Enum

   class AuthMixin(Enum):                                                                        
      if 'Production' in utils.whichBranch():
  #PRODUCTION             
         mongoport = os.environ.get("MONGO_PORT")

   ......
```

I'm trying to call it in another script.

```
    ....

    import mylib.python.auth as a
    import redis

    auth = a.AuthMixin()                                         

    ....
```

It's a No Go... Here's my error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ......
    auth = a.AuthMixin()
    TypeError: __call__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I don't understand what else I must add.
School me on the understanding.

Edit:

I think im on to the understanding....

```
   "Even though we use the class syntax to create Enums, 
   Enums are not normal Python classes. See How are Enums different? 
   for more details." - [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34][1]
```

Comment: Remove the `()`s from `auth = a.AuthMixin`.

Answer (score 1):

Note, Enum's can be instantiated, but you actually instantiate an Enum object to create a single instance of an Enum Member. In order to do so, you need to pass the index of the member within the Enum.

Refer [Programmatic access to enumeration members and their attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes)

Moreover, it is odd, the way you are trying to use the Enum. **Enumerators, are there, to enumerate a set of unique names bound to a constant value.**

Based on your usage, I apprehend, you actually never intended to instantiate `AuthMixin`, but rather want an alias for the enum, and as a particular example and use case for your exampe would be somewhat like this

```
auth = a.AuthMixin
print auth.mongoport #Access the Enumerator
```

Comment: I just took this opportunity to learn more about enums in general but a standard class would suffice, I take it.

Comment: it's odd that I had this working previous days ago but forgot to document the usage. dang!

Answer (score -1):

I think the enum class has a "_ *init* _(param)" function with param.